# How can I fix Eclipse IDE interface on a Chromebook?

Tags: linux, eclipse, interface, chromebook

I've successfully installed **Eclipse IDE** on my HP **Chromebook** x360 14c, which has Linux Debian. When the installation finished, I got a message on the **terminal**, talking about the **webkit**. And when I tried to launch the program, I saw the **buttons broken**. Fortunately, there was an update button that fixed that up. The IDE opened and I worked well. The second time I try to use it, the buttons and general interface are all broken. You can see the **pictures attached** to this post. Can anybody give me some help?[broken linux interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0tlv.png)

[terminal message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJSAW.jpg)